# Why is the array not accepting a null terminator?

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, null

I'm trying to insert a null terminator at the end of this array. How would I fix it?

```
int cool_array[10] = {0};
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    cool_array[i] = 5;
    i++;
}

cool_array[i] = {'\0'} // this is where the problem is. I get an error.
```

Error:

```
error: expected expression
legal_cards[legal_counter] = {'\0'};
                             ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, *null terminator at the end of this(**integer**) array*  doesn't make any sense. if its `char array` then it should be null terminated.

`cool_array[i] = '\0';` is not required as you already initialize `cool_array` initially as below

```
int cool_array[10] = {0}; /* here itself cool_array all elements initialized with zero */
```

**Secondly**, if `cool_array` is char array like `char cool_array[10]` then it should be

```
cool_array[i] = '\0'; /*  make sure i value is within range i.e 0 to 9 as you declare cool_array[10]  */
```

Instead of

```
cool_array[i] = {'\0'};
```

Comment: Actually there are certain instances of non-char, non-pointer arrays which are zero terminated. Examples immediately coming to mind are OpenGL WGL/GLX attribute lists.

Comment: In `C`, Correct me if I am wrong, If its  a `integer array` then we should keep track of its `length` i.e should not access out of boundary. and if its a `array of int pointer` then at last `NULL` can be passed.  sorry I am not aware of OpenGL.

Comment: @achal, you are not properly distinguishing between *code style* and language requirements.  Whether, when, and how to use terminated arrays is a matter of how you use the arrays.  Null-terminated `char` arrays are what are needed for the standard library's (and many others') string functions.  Terminated arrays of other types are fine, as are, under some circumstances, *un*terminated arrays of `char`, as long as that's what the functions you are using expect.

Comment: yes @JohnBollinger I agree. I will take care of these now onwards.

Comment: @achal: There is no such explicit requirement in C how to terminate arrays. The only requirement is, that one must be *somehow* able to identify the bounds of an array. If that happens through deidicated terminator values defined by the API, or by passing boundary parameters by a side-channel is completely left open. If an API defines "the very last element of an array passed to function X is designated by special value Y (may be limited to certain bits, actually) which must not be used otherwise" this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @achal What you are saying is, its pointless for me to stick a null terminator manually because its automatically done for me? Keep in mind that cool_array may sometimes have 9 ints to store, sometimes 3 ints, sometimes 1 int and there is no indicator telling its length.

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Normally why we initialize array(any array whether `char/int/float` array) ? So that array elements shouldn't get junk data, right ? In your case  when you do `int cool_array[10] = {0};` `cool_array` all elements initialized with `0`. so in this case you no need to write `cool_array[i] = '\0'` bcz already you initialized. And if its `integer array` & you are initialized with `'\0'` which  is `char`, read the compiler warning ?

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Instead initialized like `cool_array[i] = 0;` & make sure `i` value shouldn't exceed to no of elements i.e if you declare `cool_array[10]` then you can't write `cool_array[10] = 0;` bcz array index starts from zero. It should be `cool_array[9] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

As @achai pointed out, we usually reserve the term "null terminator" for use in connection with `char` arrays containing string data.  Nevertheless, there's nothing inherently wrong with using the value 0 as an end-of-data marker in arrays of other types, too, but such a convention is by no means universal.

You receive an error because the syntax of your terminator assignment is wrong.  You are assigning to `cool_array[i]`, which has type `int`.  The right-hand side of the assignment must therefore be an expression of type `int`.  That can be `'\0'` or (100% equivalent) just `0`, but the curly braces (`{}`) have no place there.

```
cool_array[i] = 0;
```

You are perhaps confused about the similar-appearing code in the *declaration* of `cool_array`:

```
int cool_array[10] = {0};
```

Note well that that is a declaration, not an executable statement, and there is no assignment within.  It contains an *initializer* for the array, but although that has similar form, both the syntax and semantics are different from an assignment.  Specifically, it says to initialize the first element of the array (explicitly) to 0, and implicitly to initialize all other elements (to 0).